# In Excel, Auto Filter a column based on the value selected from a Combo Box

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to auto filter a column based on the value selected from a Combo Box.

I've done this before, but I can't me remember how I did it, if I used VBA or an array formula or some kind of adapted VLOOKUP.

Specifically, I have a Combo Box showing a list of regions populated from column A of a worksheet. Column B shows a list of geographical locations and column C shows to which of those regions the location belongs.

For example:

| List of Regions | Locations | Region of Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | MegaCity1 | East |
| East | MegaCity2 | West |
| South | MegaCity3 | South |
| West | MegaCity4 | North |
|  | RuralTown1 | North |
|  | RuralTown2 | West |
|  | RuralTown3 | South |
|  | RuralTown4 | East |
|  | Village1 | South |
|  | Village2 | North |
|  | Village3 | West |
|  | Village4 | East |

When I select 'East' from the Combo Box, I would like column C to auto filter to show me only locations in the East region.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    
    Sheets("Your Excel Sheet").Select
    Columns("C").Select
    Range("C2:C13").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks so much for replying and sorry for the delay in answering. I was away for a few days. When I run this I get a run time error. 424: Object required. I'm entering the VBA in the object for the sheet specified. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Try putting the code as sheet code, not as a separate module

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a combo box and assign values.
   Go to developer=>Insert=>Form Control=>Combo box
   Right Click combo box => Format control =>Set the input range
2. Set the selected value to a cell eg, Z2
   Right Click combo box => Format control =>Cell Link
3. Then use Filter function
   FILTER(array, include, [if_empty])
   =FILTER(A2:C13, B2:B13=Z2, "No results")

Its pretty fast.